# Please tell me difference between running query directly and executing it using exec

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Please tell me what is difference
==> if i write query directly in storedprocedure 
==> and write query in string variable and than run it in exec  in stored procedure.

i am using ms sql server 2005

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some exceptions `EXEC('sql stmnt')` is what you use when you have no other choice.

It allows you to dynamically build a statement and execute it, which is often the only way of achieving something when object names are variable and not known in advance.

Read this [article](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) on dynamic SQL which explains scenarios when/why dynamic SQL is useful & goes into detail about `EXEC()`.

As for the differences between running an SQL statement in a stored procedure and running it in the procedure as `EXEC(@SQL_STRING)`:

- None of the objects referenced in `@SQL_STRING` will be [checked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190686.aspx)
- None of the T-SQL code will be verified for syntax and type checking
- Stuff in `@SQL_STRING` is within its own scope relative to the SP
- You risk being careless and poorly forming `@SQL_STRING` which can lead to security problems.
- The query plan for `@SQL_STRING` will be cached but only reused if a subsequent `EXEC(@SQL_STRING)` matches it exactly, with an SP a single query plan can be reused if all that changes are parameters.

Comment: Your last point is wrong. With any T-SQL being executed the query is hashed and compared to the saved execution plans. This means that if a variable changes, it can still re-use a plan with dynamic SQL in the same way it does with Stored Procedures. This is referenced here: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/10/who-needs-stored-procedures-anyways.html

Also you can use dynamic SQL with paremeters to avoid SQL-injection attacks as outlined here: http://www.uberasp.net/getarticle.aspx?id=46

Answer (score 0):

Diff:

- With exec statement you can create execute query which is created dynamically, stored in a variable [You have to use this in some cases].

Answer (score 0):

There's lots of fun information in the remarks section of [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx), such as:

> Changes in database context last only
>   until the end of the EXECUTE
>   statement. For example, after the EXEC
>   in this following statement is run,
>   the database context is master.

```
USE master; EXEC ('USE AdventureWorks; SELECT EmployeeID, Title FROM HumanResources.Employee;');
```

Answer (score 0):

EXEC commands with string literals is error-prone and insecure (SQL injection) since the execute just executes whatever you give it.

Check the security notice: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx